# What does "singly generated" mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, modules

Like the title says, what's the meaning of "singly generated", like in "singly generated Hilbert module". I never came across such terminology and I can't find a definition.

Comment: See second paragraph of: http://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~ilja/preprints/TFGHM.pdf

Comment: It depends on the context, but usually it means that the module is generated by a single element over the ring.

Comment: Or more generally, whenever you can talk about some structure being generated by some set, singly generated means generated by a singleton set.

Comment: So when $\mathfrak A$ is a stable C*-algebra, any countably generated Hilbert $\mathfrak A$-module $X$ is singly generated. I take it this means that there exists $a\in\mathfrak A$ such that $X=\overline{a\mathfrak A}$? Can $a$ be chosen to be positive?